# Derivation of the Fermi-Dirac distribution from combinatoric principles

Tags: solid-state-physics, differentiation, fermions

NOTE: I am aware of other methods for arriving at the Fermi-Dirac distribution, but am looking to understand this specific approach.

I am trying to follow the derivation of the Fermi-Dirac distribution which I found [here](https://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Ebart/book/fermi-dirac_derivation.htm) from combinatorics principles and have made it to the Lagrange equation

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\left(g_{i} f_{i}\right)}\left[\ln W-a \sum_{j} g_{j} f_{j}-b \sum_{j} E_{j} g_{j} f_{j}\right]=0 $$

According to that website,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\left(g_{i} f_{i}\right)} \left[a \sum_j g_j f_j \right]= a$$

which I can't follow. This would imply that $\frac{\partial}{\partial\left(g_{i} f_{i}\right)} \left[\sum_j g_j f_j \right] = 1$. From what I gather there are two options, none of which yield the result they present:

1. the dummy index is important and taking the derivative of $g_i f_i$ w.r.t $g_j f_j$ gives zero. In this case $\sum_j \frac{\partial}{\partial\left(g_{i} f_{i}\right)} g_j f_j = 0$. I don't think this is correct as $i, j$ are just dummy indices.
2. We can take $\sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial\left(g_{i} f_{i}\right)} g_i f_i = \sum_i 1 $, i.e. we get a contribution of 1 for each term ("state"), in which case the sum evaluates to the total number of states in the system (which is equal to $\sum_i g_i$ in the contect of the website).

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index $j$ is dummy index, but $i$ is **not** dummy index.

For example:
$$
   a \sum_{j=1}^3 g_j f_j = a \left\{ g_1 f_1 + g_2 f_2 + g_3 f_3\right\}.
$$

The index $i$ is one of $\{1,2,3\}$, saying $i=2$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial f_i g_i}  \sum_j  a f_j g_j &= \frac{\partial}{\partial f_2 g_2} \left\{ f_1 g_1 + f_2 g_2 + f_3 g_3 \right\} a\\
 & = \left\{\frac{\partial f_1g_1}{\partial f_2 g_2} + \frac{\partial f_2g_2}{\partial f_2 g_2} + \frac{\partial f_3g_3}{\partial f_2 g_2}\right\} a; \\
& = \left\{ 0 + 1 + 0\right\}a.
\end{align}

Comment: Ok that makes sense! Thank you!